# Opening specific Access form from a cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been researching this and cant seem to find a solution that works.  I am attempting to have a button in excel that when clicked opens access and opens a specific form.  We keep all our machine setup sheets as forms in access.

**How our operators use it:**

When you want to find your form to print out to take to the machine, you open the access db and it automatically opens the form.  You then hit "Toggle Filter" and then filter to the part number you are working with.  They then print out that form.

**How I want to use it:**

I have a cell in excel with a part number.  When a command button is clicked, it opens up the access db and filters for the specific form I want to view.

My current code is below:

```
Sub DisplayForm()

Dim StrDbpath As String
Dim PartNum As String


PartNum = Worksheets("CA Info Search").Range("A2").Value
StrDbpath = "F:\MACHSET\Setup Files.mdb"
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With appAccess
    .OpenCurrentDatabase StrDbpath
    .Visible = True
    .DoCmd.OpenForm "Machine Setup Sheet"
    
    With .Forms("Machine Setup Sheet")
        .Filter = "[PART #:]='" & PartNum & "'"
        .FilterOn = True
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

EX. Part number I am testing with is 350-0158-000

When this is ran, the db opens and prompts me to enter parameter value for Part #:.  I just hit enter and it takes me to a blank screen.  If i double check the advanced filter to see what is being filtered, it says I am filtering Part #: by '350-0158-000' but the form is still blank

[1][Parameter Prompt]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dEuc.png

[2][Blank screen after I hit enter]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dexzK.png

[3][Advanced Filter]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eUsX.png

[4][Advanced filter showing filter value]
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnXN2.png

Comment: Shouldn't the *WhereCondition* argument be : `"[PART #]=" & PartNum`?

Comment: so maybe:   appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "Machine Setup Sheet", , , "[PART #]=" & PartNum   ??

Comment: I just tried that. Now the Access DB opens and prompts me to "Enter Parameter Value" for PART#.  When i do enter the part number manually it doesnt open it

Comment: I tried just using 2 commas, and it doesnt seem to take.  I think the three commas is correct.  But when I open the DB there is already a filter on for the PN.  Is there a way to clear it first?

Comment: Check the column name `[PART #]` is correct - it shouldn't be asking for a parameter unless you've set one. To clear the filter you need to set the `FilterOn = False` property on the form.

Comment: When I try to clear previous filter, this code gets flagged.  `appAccess.DoCmd.FilterOn = False`

Comment: That's because `FilterOn` is not a property of the `DoCmd` object, it's a form property. The code should read : `appAccess.Forms.YourFormName.FilterOn = False` after the form has been loaded. Otherwise do it on the `Form_Load()` event on the form directly.

Comment: Ok, @KostasK. I think I am really close.  i updated the post to show the code I am using now.  It is prompting me with that "Enter Parameter" thing still, but when I hit enter it filters using cell A2 value, but it changes the value.  ex. the part number 350-0158-000 changes to 350-158-0

Comment: PartNum `350-0158-000` is a string, so you must enclose it in quotes: `"[PART #:]='" & PartNum & "'"`

Comment: ^^^ This. Plus you load the form twice. The form should not be filtered by default, if you need a filter, you should apply it when opening the form. But the form itself should be clear from any static filters.

Answer (score 1):

Too much to put in a comment.

To continue from my last comment, you don't need to open the form again, just apply the filter. Try the below (I've no means to test it).

```
'...
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With appAccess
    .OpenCurrentDatabase strDbPath
    .Visible = True
    .DoCmd.OpenForm "Machine Setup Sheet"
    
    With .Forms("Machine Setup Sheet")
        .Filter = "[PART #:]='" & PartNum & "'"
        .FilterOn = True
    End With
End With
```

Setting the `.FilterOn = True` property, will reset and reapply the filter.

Comment: the filter still is not working.  When I manually filter the data for a certain part number it shows up as filter for "350-0158-000".  but when I run this code I get '350-0158-000' with the single quote marks.  Ive been playing around with the code, but cant get the double quotes to show up

Comment: I also noticed that when I filter manually the Part #: part does not have [ ] around it.  but when i run my code it does.  I think that may be an issue as well

Comment: Please don't edit and change the question entirely as it's needed for context for the answer. Instead, add the edited code below the original question.

Comment: The brackets [ ] are needed when field names contain spaces. Also, the double quotes " " are needed to wrap a string, they shouldn't be visible. Are they part of the value in the table by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

weird bug that goes away.  the problems occur because the spaces in the form name and the with statement, but once I fixed those problems, I could put the spaces and with statement back.  Hence, I couldn't verify the answer.
assumptions you have a worksheet named CA Info Search. A2 is formatted general and that cell shows 350-0158-000. Also form is named Machine Setup Sheet and actually has a column named Part #:
try this code:

```
Sub DisplayForm()
Dim StrDbpath As String
Dim PartNum As String
PartNum = Worksheets("CA Info Search").Range("A2").Value
StrDbpath = "F:\MACHSET\Setup Files.mdb"
Set appaccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
appaccess.OpenCurrentDatabase StrDbpath
appaccess.docmd.OpenForm "Machine Setup Sheet"
appaccess.Forms("Machine Setup Sheet").Filter = "[PART #:]='" & PartNum & "'" 'need the apostrophes to indicate 350-0158-000 is a string
appaccess.Forms("Machine Setup Sheet").FilterOn = True
appaccess.Visible = True
End Sub
```

If the above code doesn't work, then remove the spaces from the form name and adjust the code accordingly.  Replace all instances "Machine Setup Sheet" with "MachineSetupSheet".  Then if the code works and you want the with statement and "Machine Setup Sheet", try adding them back in.
Solution worked in Access and Excel 2016